# What is machine config in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hai ,

I am doing a web project in asp.net. Now I am trying to keep each connection string for each user . And the user can decide which server he prefer. How to change this dynamically and where can I store this?. I happen heard about machine.config .Unfortunately i am not familiar with this. Can you just tell what it is and it's use. If any disadvantages please tell.
    And How it use?

Answer (score 2):

Machine.config is a "global" set of configuration settings. All websites on your server use the settings set in Machine.config, and they can be overridden with settings in Web.config. See [Machine Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697.aspx) on MSDN.

If the connectionstring is unique to each user, web.config (or machine.config) is probably not the location where you'd want to store it.
But if I assume you're only going to deal with a handful of connections (i.e. NOT a unique connection per user), you could create the connections in web.config and then just store a reference for each user.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="cnn1" connectionString="[your connectionstring]" />
    <add name="cnn2" connectionString="[your connectionstring]" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Where do you store user specific data? ASP.NET Membership? Something handrolled?

Comment: That is am asking u? where can I store?

Comment: I have a doubt. If we edit Web config at run time,will the server restart?

Comment: Your app will recycle. The server will not restart.

Answer (score 1):

Its usage (I am talking for web.config):

Writing connection strings manually is difficult especially when you don't know its syntax. So,

1.Add a SqlDataSource (if your db is mssql)
2.Point it to your .mdf file
3.It will ask whether it should save it to web.config
4.say "yes" and give a name to that string
5.Now you have a connectionstring with a name
6.Then you can manipulate it

Answer (score 0):

I don't advice you to use that file, it is server wide configuration file, use web.config that is application wide.

Meantime, why do you want to store connection string for each user?